# Android: alignment of images according to device size?

Tags: android

I am having three images or buttons in a linear layout which fits fine on large devices, but when it comes to small devices, what should i do so that the third image comes in the next line (in small devices, it would be aligned properly in landscape but it would go out of the screen in the portrait mode).

[image]

XML code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="left" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/stopServiceButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/stop_service_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/calibrateButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/calibrate_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:padding="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/doneButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/done_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:padding="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use different layout, drawables for different dpi(hdpi, mdpi etc) http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: yea i am using different dpi's but i guess there should be a way to reposition images/buttons in android according to the device..Was thinking that LinearLayout would take care of it.

Comment: i had past code use that it will work fine for you..

Comment: And don't Give any fix size to any controls,,ok.

Comment: layout-weight was the missing factor... :) Was not much aware of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to use `layout_weight` attribute,this way

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:weight_sum="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="left" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/stopServiceButton" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/stop_service_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:paddingRight="5dp" android:paddingTop="5dp"/> 

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/calibrateButton" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/calibrate_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:padding="5dp"/> 

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/doneButton" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/done_button_selector" android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left" android:padding="5dp"/> 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had modify your code,, set images on button then see, it work Fine...

```
       <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"        
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <Button  
       android:id="@+id/aa"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/stop_service_button_selector"/>


    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"        
       android:layout_weight="1">
       <Button  
       android:id="@+id/bb"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/calibrate_button_selector"/>     


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"        
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <Button  
       android:id="@+id/cc"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/done_button_selector"/>


    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```